# Only video, no audio

Tags: android

This is strange but this is my project requirement. In my project i want to play a video with audio suppression. For audio we have another plan. So i can use VideoView to play a video. But this plays audio of that file as well(which is not require for me). So how can i achieve this strange requirement, i.e Playing video without audio. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: set the sound to mute form code may do the trick.

Comment: Hi Andru, Actually we play audio parallel to video. But we will apply some post processing to it. mute is not a good idea.

Comment: Is there any API which plays only video of file not audio.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3197282/1777090). No idea of any API which plays just video and not audio.

Comment: @MysticMagic: Your link is helpful to me. Now i have another question. I set the sound to mute, MUSIC_STREAM with your suggested code.Now if i play audio samples using audiotrack object, will it play sound or it will be in mute?

Comment: I have not implemented yet. But if that object is different, then it should play.

Comment: @MysticMagic: Yes that audioTrack object is different. By using MediaExtractor API i am playing audio samples separately using audioTrack Object. So will it work for me?

Comment: It SHOULD. Try it.. And let me know. I am curious, too. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43976/discussion-between-saa-and-mystic-magic)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this in my opinion is to set the volume to 0 when the video is ready. All the other solutions I've found imply the use of deprecated API which mute the whole system.

This is a simple solution

```
VideoView videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        videoPreview.setOnPreparedListener(
                new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                    {
                        mp.setVolume(0f, 0f);
                    }
                }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

This link
[Supplying option to user to play video with or without audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196129/supplying-option-to-user-to-play-video-with-or-without-audio/3197282#3197282) helped me to mute my video's sound. Then by using MediaExtractor, AudioTrack API(s) i can extract audio samples from file and then i can play those extracted samples using AudioTrack object. Only precaution that i have to take is while creating AudioTrack object use AudioManager.STREAM_RING

```
audioTrack= new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 44100, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

So videoView plays my video but i can't hear audio because STREAM_MUSIC is in mute, audioTrack object plays my audio separately.